# Passing 'mar' graphical parameter to plot function

Tags: r, plot, parameter-passing

I am confused about the fact that specifying the `mar` graphical parameter in the `plot` function does not work. The following would give you two identical plots:

```
plot(1:10, 10:1, xlab = "x", ylab = "y", mar = c(10, 0, 0, 0))
plot(1:10, 10:1, xlab = "x", ylab = "y", mar = c(0, 0, 0, 0))
```

However, if I try to specify other graphical parameters, such as `col.lab` in the example below, it works as expected. The below would give plots with different colours of the labels:

```
plot(1:10, 10:1, xlab = "x", ylab = "y", col.lab = "red")
plot(1:10, 10:1, xlab = "x", ylab = "y", col.lab = "black")
```

Confusingly, specifying the `mar` graphical parameter outside of the function works fine, as in:

```
par.default <- par()
par(mar = c(10, 0, 0, 0))
plot(1:10, 10:1, xlab = "x", ylab = "y")
par(par.default)
```

Is there a way to fix this (in my eyes) unexpected behaviour?

Comment: It's a fair question, and perhaps it speaks to spiral development of graphics and such over the decades. For me this behavior indicates a slight inconsistency in how options are passed. I can't find an easy answer why [ProcessInlinePars](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/5a156a0865362bb8381dcd69ac335f5174a4f60c/src/library/graphics/src/par.c#L1250) isn't mapping it correctly, so I suspect any solution would require fixing deep internals of R, idk. Fix? Use `par(mar=...)` or write a wrapper function that checks `...` args against `names(par())` and handles them explicitly. (Untested!)

Answer (score 6):

There are three different types of graphical parameter used in R:

- Normal (`ptype 0` in [the underlying C code](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/bd427071410d9f717568487e3499814ce0caa1d1/src/library/graphics/src/par.c#L58)).
- Non-inline, (`ptype 1`, meaning it can be set by the user via `par`, but not inline via high-level functions).
- Read-only. (`ptype 2`, which cannot be set by the user at all, but is fixed according to the graphics device).

`mar` is of the non-inline type. If you read the documentation for `?par`, then the **Details** section lists all of the other graphical parameters that *cannot* be set in a call to high-level plotting functions, i.e. all of the non-inline parameters :

> Several parameters can only be set by a call to par():
>
> - "ask",
> - "fig", "fin",
> - "lheight",
> - "mai", "mar", "mex", "mfcol", "mfrow", "mfg",
> - "new",
> - "oma", "omd", "omi",
> - "pin", "plt", "ps", "pty",
> - "usr",
> - "xlog", "ylog",
> - "ylbias"
>
> The remaining parameters can also be set as arguments (often via `...`) to high-level plot functions

These parameters are all handled by the C function [Specify](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/bd427071410d9f717568487e3499814ce0caa1d1/src/library/graphics/src/par.c#L233), whereas the `ptype 0` parameters, which *can* be used in high level plotting functions, are handled by the C function [Specify2](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/bd427071410d9f717568487e3499814ce0caa1d1/src/library/graphics/src/par.c#L647).

It is clear that these assignations are not random, but a conscious design choice. I could easily tell a just-so story about *why* they were designed this way; for example, if I make a scatter plot then want to add lines, annotations, titles or legends to it, then I would have to use the same `mar` argument in my calls to `lines`, `axis`, `legend` etc to ensure the plot areas were matching, and this would feel like worse design than having to set `mar` in advance. *"Why can't I just set this once before I plot and be done with it!?"*

But the actual reasons behind this design would need to come from the developers themselves (or perhaps even from the developers of the GRZ library, [on which the `par` system was based](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/bd427071410d9f717568487e3499814ce0caa1d1/src/library/graphics/src/par.c#LL24C6-L24C50) ).

As for how to get round this, there is little that can be done other than defining a new high-level plotting function that sets the `mar`, plots, then resets the old `mar`:

```r
plot_with_mar <- function(mar = par('mar'), ...) {
  parmar <- par('mar')
  par(mar = mar)
  plot(...)
  par(mar = parmar, new = FALSE)
  invisible(NULL)
}
```

This could be used as a drop in for `plot`:

```r
set.seed(1)

x <- 1:10
y <- rnorm(10)

plot_with_mar(x, y, mar = c(2, 2, 2, 2))
```

[image]

```r
plot_with_mar(x, y, mar = c(8, 8, 8, 8))
```

[image]

If this feels a bit clunky, then consider that this is in effect what all the built-in high-level plotting functions in R do. Also, if you try to add lines or annotations after plotting with `plot_with_mar`, you will quickly find out how tiresome it would be to try to do things this way round.

<sup>Created on 2022-11-17 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>